# python 3.8 venv missing activate command

Tags: python, python-venv, python-3.8

I compiled Python 3.8.1 under a user's home directory with

```
configure --prefix=/home/a_user/python3.8 --enable-shared
```

1. When I tried to use venv, I get:

```
python3 -m venv test_env
Error: Command '['/home/a_user/test_env/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

2. test_env is created but incomplete:

```
test_env/
├── bin
│   ├── python -> python3
│   └── python3 -> /home/a_user/python3.8/bin/python3
├── include
├── lib
│   └── python3.8
│       └── site-packages
├── lib64 -> lib
└── pyvenv.cfg

6 directories, 3 files
```

3. ensurepip does exist:

```
python3 -m ensurepip
Looking in links: /tmp/tmpeqrn78f5
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (41.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (19.2.3)
```

So I am clueless as to what's missing.

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: If you run that command manually – `test_env/bin/python3 -Im ensurepip --upgrade --default-pip` – does it show any output?

Comment: I am using openSUSE LEAP 15.1

Comment: <code>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
.... some lines removed
  File "/home/user/python3.8/lib/python3.8/tempfile.py", line 45, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "/home/user/python3.8/lib/python3.8/random.py", line 41, in <module>
    from math import log as _log, exp as _exp, pi as _pi, e as _e, ceil as _ceil
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'math'
</code>

Comment: If I remove the "I" and run ```test_env/bin/python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade --default-pip``` it works  
```Looking in links: /tmp/tmp73vwpom8

Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in ./test_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (41.2.0)  
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./test_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (19.2.3)```

Comment: math module works fine in this test. ```test_env/bin/python3
Python 3.8.1 (default, Jan  2 2020, 02:56:40) 
[GCC 7.4.1 20190905 [gcc-7-branch revision 275407]] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import math

>>> math.factorial(4)
24```

Comment: I think the problem is with ```-Im```.  According to help ```-I     : isolate Python from the user's environment (implies -E and -s)```.  And since my Python 3.8 is compiled to a custom directory, without the user's environment, of course it won't find it.

Comment: I am able to create a venv using the --without-pip option.
python3 -m venv --without-pip test_env

Answer (score 9):

The final solution is:

```
python3 -m venv --without-pip test_env
source test_env/bin/activate
python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Now the virtual env is fully set and working.

Answer (score 2):

Just updated to last python's version, the output says it all:

```
apt-get install python3-venv
```

After that creating env with

```
python3 -m venv test_venv
```

works as expected, creating *activate* scritp.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Vadim's answer because I cannot comment yet.

So if your having problems check to see if your desired version of python-venv is available and install it.

Replace the 3.x with your version. If there are packages available they will show up in the output.

`sudo apt search python3.7-venv`

I had installed python3.7, so I did

`sudo apt install python3.7-venv`

instead of

`sudo apt install python3-venv`

Edit:

A great tool for using python virtual environments is pyenv. Easy to set up and intuitive to use. This solves python versioning easily. You still have to make your python venv and activate it but you can easily install any version of python there is.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if you have fresh os install, install first pip by following commands

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

After installing you can create virtual environment & would have activate script