# cannot create python virtual environment (exit status 101)

Tags: python, virtual-environment

When I try to generate a virtual environment, the following error pops up on Windows 11:

```
PS C:\programming\tmp> python -m venv venv
Error: Command '['C:\\programming\\tmp\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 101.
```

I have uninstalled all versions of python I did reinstall python 3.10.1 but the error remains.
Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61641280/python3-8-venv-returned-exit-status-101/62207756#62207756) I did try to install it for all users with no success.
I also added python to PATH.

My guess is that it is related to `pip`, since `python -m venv --without-pip venv_no_pip` works (but I need pip thus this is no good solution).

I would appreciate any hint on what to do since I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Have you tried updating `pip`? `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows Python (<=3.10.2) fails to run \`python -m venv .venv\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71039131/windows-python-3-10-2-fails-to-run-python-m-venv-venv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same problem (well, all users install did work on my PC) and found a solution. If your python is installed on a path with a space, check out my [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71041562/4516027)

Comment: This was indeed also the problem on my computer. Surprisingly, it was no problem in the past.

Comment: @user7431005 - right? Some account-specific change in Windows triggers this behavior. I filed a bug report to python, and they acknowledged it. So hopefully it'll get fixed soon