# Error: Command '['C:\\Users\\u\\de\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 101

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

Whenever I try to create virtual environment in python I get this error

> Error: Command '['C:\Users\u\Desktop\venv\Scripts\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 101.

I am using Windows 10.
I tried uninstalling python and reinstalled it several times but still the problem continues.

I have been using python on my computer from years but now I am facing this error.

Comment: Maybe worth ensuring you have the "install for all users" option selected. Refer to the answer here; https://stackoverflow.com/a/62207756/1199464

Comment: I selected that option as well but still its not working

Answer (score 0):

just delete your current python directory and reload it again from official web page
[enter link description here](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error when I already had a venv folder in my current working folder.  See if you have one.. if you do delete it and try again and it should work.

Might need to go to view-command pallette-select intepreter- then select python venv if using vscode after the first step.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on a redhat server while trying to make a python venv as a non-root user.

Here is a detailed output on why the venv creation fail.

```
$ python-venv/bin/python3 -Im ensurepip --upgrade --default-pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _SETUPTOOLS_VERSION = _get_most_recent_wheel_version("setuptools")
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 18, in _get_most_recent_wheel_version
    return str(max(versions, key=distutils.version.LooseVersion))
```

I don't have a mean to verify if the python installation is correct, but I assume it isn't.